# views grouping by field type in a row

Tags: views

Here is what i get in views:

(first-row)
node1title
node1body

(second-row)
node2title
node2body

---

and this is what i want:

(first-row)
node1title
node2title

(node2-row)
node1body
node2body

is it possible to get it in a single view?

Comment: Groupping in display format sessings?

Answer (score 0):

one possible answer is to add views php module add php code in for titles and then for body.

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer

Comment: Write code to load all titles nd den body part 4 al titles nd body seprate divs.